# Why some triphthongs are retained orthographically in Arabic, but not others

Tags: orthography, arabic, triphthongs

According to Ahmad Al-Jallad's "A manual of the historical grammar of Arabic", a sound change from old to classical Arabic was the collapse of triphthongs.

These triphthongs are sometimes preserved in orthography, like in صَلَوة which is orthographically "ṣ-l-w-h/t", but pronounced "ṣaláh" as though it were "ṣ-l-'-h/t" (although this was not one of Al-Jallad's examples).It is worth noting however, that nowadays this word is sometimes spelt صَلاة ["ṣ-l-'-h/t"], which is a more phonetic spelling, as most are in Arabic, and doesn't preserve the historical triphthong.

However triphthongs are not always preserved in orthography, like in رَضُوا which is written "r-ḍ-w-'" and is pronounced "raḍú", with the "'" being silent (which is a normal grammatical phenomenon in Arabic) however the origin of the word is "raḍawú", so should be written رَضَوُوا "r-ḍ-w-w-'" if the triphthong were to be preserved orthographically.

My first question is why it is only preserved sometimes. My best guess is that this may have something to do with how the plural of صَلَوة is صَلَوات, which is "ṣ-l-w-'-t" orthographically and is pronounced "ṣalawát", so the triphthong is pronounced, which is then reflected in the singular form. In contrast, the root "r-ḍ-'" has no form (that comes to mind) in which the "w" is pronounced, so there is no use of reflecting the lost "w" orthographically in that one form where it was.

My second question is one regarding the word هاتِف ("h-'-t-f", "hátif"), which has the plural form هَواتِف ("h-w-'-t-f", "hawátif"). It is unlikely for the "morphological weight" (وزن صرفي, I don't know The proper English word for it) of the plural to be فَواعِل ("fawá`il") as most فاعِل words have the plural template فاعِلون. My other guess would be that there was an underlying four letter root, but because those are extremely rare, and most have the same two letters in succession, like زلزل ("z-l-z-l"), the "w" was elided in most forms to make it look more normal, but somehow it was preserved in the plural. This again raises the question of why it is not reflected orthographically in the singular, when it is in صَلوة.

Comment: Note that the term "triphthong" is used inappropriately in the book and traditional Semitic linguistics: a triphthong is a sequence of three vowels within one syllable, this is an intervocalic glide. You may want to look at https://scholarlypublications.universiteitleiden.nl/access/item%3A3139877/view

Comment: @user6726 , but the glide was already there, and did not appear to clarify the two vowels. So if you call a sequence like /ei/ a diphthong, where the second “vowel” is not syllabic and therefore more like glide, I don’t see why you can’t call this a triphthong.